# JSP regarding prints

Tags: java

Updating to other post where question is answered already.

Comment: Hi Evan, you didn't post the class for `Loan` but it probably doesn't find any constructor accepting an int. That's about it :)

Answer (score 1):

You should use the accessors from your `Loan` object since you haven't defined any constructor accepting parameters (or defined but not made them accessible - e.g `private`).

```
Loan loanAmount = new Loan(Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("loanAmount")));
```

Can be replaced by for example

```
Loan loan = new Loan();
load.setAmount(Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("loanAmount")));
```

Comment: You're right. it does not make sense without the object. ive added my object and updated my processor to " 

Loan loan = new Loan();
 loan.printScheduleItem(Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("loanAmount")));